# VBA script with excel and IE

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I'm trying to open an .xlsx file with values in column A (let's say A1:A1000).

I need the script to select the value from A1 and add it to a URL. It then needs to open the URL and change a setting on that specific site. It should then confirm the change and go on to the next value A2 and do the same until the last value (a loop).

I've come up with he following:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")    
 IE.Visible = 1    
 IE.navigate "http://xxxx/edit_product.php?Prod_ID=45306"    
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 100    
 Loop    
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("Status")    
 Helem.Value = "The change I need" 
 Do While (IE.Busy)    
     WScript.Sleep 100   
Loop     
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

In this code the prod_ID "45306" in the URL is the value coming from the cell so that should be a variable value.

The action on the site works but how do I open an Excel file and loop the action (and make the URL variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of JazzzyJoop I was able to get the script needed :D Thanks JazzyJoop. Below the code for anyone having to need the same thing

```
Dim xlApp, wb, ws 
Dim filename, LastRow, prodID


Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\attachment1.xlsx") 'Set path to your file
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Set name of your worksheet
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 

    For i = 1 To 4 'Range of values
        prodID = ws.Range("A" & i).Value

        IE.navigate "http://xxxx/edit_product.php?Prod_ID=" & prodID
        Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 50
    Loop
    IE.Document.getElementById("Status").Value = "Status Needed"
    WScript.Sleep 100 
    Set oInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each elm In oInputs
            If elm.Value = "Verwerk" Then
                elm.Click
                Exit For
            End If
    Next
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            WScript.Sleep 50
        Loop


    Next

wb.Close False
xlApp.Quit

set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to run this code from another workbook and then open a different workbook where the values are?

Try this:

```
    Dim lr As Long, prodID as string
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="c:\temp\attachment.xlsx") 'Set path to your file
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Set name of your worksheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last row used in column A

        For i = 1 To lr
            prodID = ws.Range("A" & i).Value

            IE.navigate "http://xxxx/edit_product.php?Prod_ID=" & prodID
            Do While (IE.Busy)
                WScript.Sleep 100
            Loop
            Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("Status")
            Helem.Value = "The change I need"
            Do While (IE.Busy)
                 WScript.Sleep 100
            Loop
            Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
            Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        Next
```

Comment: Apart from an error saying end of instruction expected on row 1 sign 8 I'm not sure what you mean by the question asked above your code. I just have 1 workbook with 1 sheet (sheet1) which contains a list in Colom 1 (A1:A1000). The value in each cell of colum A needs to be added to the url before the action takes place. This has to be done for all values in Colom A. Hope that makes my question clearer :) Thanks for your help so far!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "how do I open an Excel file and loop the action?" From where do you want to run the code?

I interpreted your problem as: "I have an excel file open in which I have a macro. The macro needs to open an Excel file and loop through the cells of that file."

Comment: Oh no I just made a seperate VBS file which I run to do the action. Tried it in excel (ALT F11) vbs but got some issues getting IE to start so tried it in a seperate .vbs and that helped with the IE issues. So that's why I need the vbs to open the .xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here it goes for vbs.

I'm not too familiar with vbs, but try the code below. If you run into any errors, just let me know.

```
Dim xlApp, wb, ws 
Dim filename, LastRow, prodID

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\attachment.xls") 'Set path to your file
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Set name of your worksheet
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 

    For i = 1 To 10
        prodID = ws.Range("A" & i).Value

        IE.navigate "http://xxxx/edit_product.php?Prod_ID=" & prodID
        Do While (IE.Busy)
            WScript.Sleep 100
        Loop
        Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("Status")
        Helem.Value = "The change I need"
        Do While (IE.Busy)
             WScript.Sleep 100
        Loop
        Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Shell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Next

wb.Close False
xlApp.Quit

set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Unfortionatly I do get errors running this script. First error was Expected ')' row 5 sign 39. I googled it and I believe I can just say Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\attachment.xlsx") But after doing so i get an unknown runtime error row 7 sign 1. Not sure what it means but I'm afraid it's not working yet. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ok, so I've changed the code above and tested it. It opened up IE and navigated to the right url. The only thing is, you have to hardcode the number of rows in the loop (currently set at 10).

Comment: Wow that is already way better. It opens the right excel and performs the action needed on the first value. It then goes to the second value and returns an error Object needed 'Helem' row 18 sign 9 so I think the loop doesn't work entirely yet.

Comment: Error "Object needed 'Helem'" probably means that IE can't find an element with the ID 'Status' on your page. Are you sure the URL is right?

Comment: Yes i'm sure the value is correct. I even get the error if i make cell A2 the same as A1. It should just overwrite the first change with the second change but it just outputs the error :-(

Comment: The loop works fine. If I comment out 'Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("Status")' and I run a loop on the URL stackoverflow.com with a range of question id's, it works just fine. So, the issue is with that line. Without knowing your URL and the id's I cannot debug this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found that the sendkeys were giving issues. Commenting those out solved it but now i'm having trouble confirming the changes I made previously. Do you know how to alter the code to confirm the changes by pressing: <input type="submit" name="action" value="Verwerk"> Issue is the ID Action is also used for other actions so I need to be able to use the value "Verwerk"

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14823317/3020949). Refer to the part 'Set oInputs' until 'Next'. Change "I accept" to "Verwerk". That should work.

Comment: Thanks JazzzyJoop thanks to that link and some minor alterations the script works!!! Thank you ever so much!